# ToString(string) not formatting a float? as I would expect it to

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I am working with a WinForms application, displaying a string in the view after formatting it.

Here is how I attempt to format the number:

```
reportData.VelocityRangeStart.ToString(reportData.Velocity.FormatString)
```

Below is the result of using the Immediate Window in Visual Studio:

```
reportData.VelocityRangeStart
12.5996475    // output
reportData.Velocity.FormatString
"#,##0.000"    // output
reportData.VelocityRangeStart.ToString(reportData.Velocity.FormatString)
"12.59965"    // output
12.5996475f.ToString("#,##0.000")
"12.600"    // output
```

Can someone please explain what I'm missing?  I expect `"12.600"` in that case.  FYI: `reportData.VelocityRangeStart` is of `float?` type.

Comment: try this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please check out [MCVE] guidance - whatever code you've posted is very confusing.

Comment: What is the type of `reportData.VelocityRangeStart`? Does casting it into a float first change the result?

Comment: If you do `reportData.VelocityRangeStart.Value.ToString(reportData.Velocity.FormatString)` does it still do that?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I mentioned this was my interaction with the Immediate Window in Visual Studio in the question.  This is a direct copy and paste from that.  I added comments to clarify

Comment: @JakeSmith while you may find it funny and entertaining readers of your post have to figure out what is related to the question and what is not. Should one focus on CS1733? or CS1001? Simple one line sample `Console.WriteLine(((float?)12.5996475f).ToString("#,##0.000"));` would be clear and to the point (also it does not compile - but you already know that by the answer provided )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, removed the jokes.  Code still won't compile if you paste the whole thing at once.  But if you copy and paste each input line, you have convenience right at your finger tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nullable types shouldn't even have `ToString()` overload with format string. You need to use `reportData.VelocityRangeStart.Value.ToString(reportData.Velocity.FormatString)` to get the formatting work.

And don't forget to check for null in the value first! So

```
reportData.VelocityRangeStart.HasValue ? reportData.VelocityRangeStart.Value.ToString(reportData.Velocity.FormatString) : "is null"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Is the behavior of this indicative of a bug?

Comment: and where the hell he did mentioned is using nullable type. @Sami or its just an arrow in the dark

Comment: @Dot_NETPro Maybe right in the end where it says the type?

Comment: @JakeSmith It's just how Nullable types work. Since not all types have ToString() with a format string I assume they didn't add it to Nullable itself and it has to be handled manually.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary wording in the last paragraph to bring more emphasis to my mention of the type for future reference.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, thanks.  I just find it odd that it seemed to format it.  No errors or anything, it would just format to the wrong number of decimal places.  Quite odd, indeed.

Comment: @JakeSmith I would check if there's some extension method somewhere since Nullable by itself doesn't provide a version with format string at all from what I can find in the documentation

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of that.  You are probably right about there being an extension method I haven't ran across yet.  Thanks again, I really appreciate you helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use this:

```
float VelocityRangeStart=12.5996475F;
string strVelocityRangeStart=VelocityRangeStart.ToString();
Console.WriteLine((Math.Ceiling(Double.Parse(strVelocityRangeStart)).ToString()));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't want that. Try and see what it outputs.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling(reportData.VelocityRangeStart).ToString()
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float?' to 'decimal'`